# How to make chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener distinguish for different context menu ids?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, custom-contextmenu

While developing contextmenu based extension for Chrome, i'm facing a situation where invoking `chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener` in a loop adds action cumulatively for each subcontext menu item.

So, when subcontextmenu is clicked it triggers event listener for all subcontext menus, instead for the context menu which was clicked.

```
     var parent;
     chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
        parent = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "CCM", "id":"CCM", "contexts":["selection"]});
     });


     Object.keys(msgs).forEach(function(key) {
        chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
        var createCM = chrome.contextMenus.create(
            {"title": "subcontextmenu"+key, "id":"scm"+key, "parentId": parent, "contexts":["selection"]});
        }); 
        chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info,tab){openAction(info,tab,JSON.stringify(msgs[key]['msg']));}
        );  
     });
```

In the above example, `msgs` is a JSON object containing message to be displayed when each subcontextmenu is clicked. Also, the `msgs` JSON context is bound to change dynamically. So, we can't tweak `openAction` to hardcode the numbers and associate the messages.

Hope my question is clear. Any help for clearing this confusion will be a great time saver for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one listener for onInstalled and onClicked (it provides [menuItemId](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/#type-OnClickData) in its parameter).

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({title: 'CCM', id: 'CCM', contexts: ['selection']});
  Object.keys(msgs).forEach(key => {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
      title: 'subcontextmenu' + key,
      id: 'scm' + key,
      parentId: 'CCM',
      contexts: ['selection'],
    });
  });
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  openAction(info, tab, JSON.stringify(msgs[info.menuItemId].msg));
});
```

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm for the quick reply. This again saved me time and trouble in understanding the problem. Your solution worked. Thank you so much.